# Locating Template Manager in Joomla 3.4.7

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla and just created a site in Joomla 3.4.7. My goal is to be able to edit the HTML of the template I have selected so that I may embed some code in between the head tags.

From tutorials I have watched, I do this by going the dashboard, clicking extensions > template manager, then it should take me to the files. However, when I click on the extensions tab, I only see "templates" and no source code.

I have also tried locating the module manager which should be available to me when clicking on the extensions tab. It is not there. I only see "modules, plugins, templates, languages." The same goes for extension manager.

Have these all been deprecated in version 3.4.7? Or are they located somewhere else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's still there.

Go to **Extensions** >> **Templates**

Then on the left sidebar, click **Templates** (under *Styles*)

Then select the template you wish to edit and open the **index.php** file

[image]

Comment: When I click on templates then click on the template I wish to edit, in this case "Protostar details and files", it just has an image preview underneath "template description. There is no index.php file.

Comment: @user3700231 - Hmm odd. The screenshot I provided in my answer if what you *should* see along the process

Comment: You may not be authorized to edit the template. Are you a super admin? can you check the permissions?

Comment: Hey guys, MY BAD. I was trying to edit templates on a Joomla.com site, not a .org. The joomla.com site does not allow you to edit templates. Ultra noob here (hanging head low). I'm off to download the full fledged CMS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not authorized to view those resources.  The things you want to view are generally only available to those with global admin rights. If this has changed it may be that someone change the assignments of permission for a group of which you are a member. In particular if you are a member of a group that is hard denied for admin for modules and templates, you will no longer be able to access those interfaces. It's a little hard to know exactly without seeing your groups and permissions structure for those components, but I'd check for a hard deny somewhere.